# Evento onclick no responde

Tags: javascript, html

Estoy tratando de ejecutar este código:

```
    <style type="text/css">
        #boton{
            width: 50px;
            height: 30px;
            display: block;
            margin:30px;
        }

        img{
            width: 300px;
            height: 200px;
            margin:30px;
        }
    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var boton = document.getElementById('boton');
        boton.onclick = function(){
            var imagen = document.getElementById('foto');
            imagen.style.display ='none';
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="boton">Click</button>
    <img src="header.jpg" id="foto">
</body>
```

El problema es que no carga el evento `onclick` de ninguna de las formas. También he intentado crear la función antes y llamarla cuando se suceda el evento, pero no funciona. De la única forma que me funciona es introduciendo el código de forma inline, y no quiero hacerlo así. La idea es hacer todo el código [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) en un archivo aparte.

Comment: Jogofus, acabo de convertir tu codigo tal cual en un ejecutable con los snippets y funciona bien. https://jsfiddle.net/lois6b/w8m8e97x/

Comment: Te recomiendo, que limpies tus scripts de la página en Chrome (cntrl + F5) o prueba tu código utilizando depuradores de internet.

Comment: He probado con 3 navegadores: Chrome, Opera y Edge y en ninguno me ha funcionado. @lois6b acabo de probarlo en la pagina que me has mandado y veo que funciona perfectamente. ¿Por que a mi no me funciona en los navegadores abriendo el fichero .html?

Comment: @lois6b fyi [window.onload = function(){...}](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KfGq6.png) :)

Comment: es porbable que el archivo que tiene el script no se este llamando, revisa si es la ruta correcta

Comment: Es simple, no funciona porque primero se ejecuta el script y para ese momento el tag `<button id="boton">` **NO EXISTE**, te he colocado una respuesta con un ejemplo que si funciona, por otro lado lo que hace no es una buena practica, lo correcto es que el código **javascript** lo coloques al final de la pagina y de ser posible en un archivo aparte, Saludos!! ;))...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Es posible que pueda deberse a que el documento aún no se ha terminado de parsear y cargar.

Como recomendación, algunos puntos importantes:

**Sé consciente del proceso de parseo y carga del HTML**

Todo documento pasa por una etapa de parseo y finalmente se carga y pasa a estar disponible. El DOM (Object Document Model) es una interface que te permite interactuar con el documento. Esta interface es la encargada de interactuar con el HTML almacenando cada etiqueta en un *Nodo* dentro de un árbol, el cual no es más que la representación de la etiqueta en una interface.

¿Qué tiene que ver esto con tu pregunta? Que cuando interaccionas con el documento cuando aún no ha sido completamente cargado, es muy probable que obtengas una referencia nula **porque aún no ha sido parseado y no está disponible en el árbol DOM**.

Una buena práctica es seleccionar los elemetos **cuando el documento ha sido cargado**. En [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) puro se hace capturando el evento `DOMContentLoaded`:

```
 document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    // selecciona los elementos aquí
});
```

En [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery) se hace mediante el evento personalizado `ready`:

```
$(document).on('ready', function() {
    // selecciona los elementos aquí
});
```

Así te aseguras que los nodos estén disponibles en el árbol DOM.

**No pongas scripts en la cabecera**

A no ser que marques estos scripts con el atributo `async` o `defer`, no los pongas en la cabecera porque el parseo del documento no proseguirá hasta que los scripts hayan sido resueltos. En su lugar pon los scripts antes del cierre del body:

```
<script>
    // código abcdeghi
</script>
</body>
```

Ten en cuenta estos puntos al interactuar con los elementos.

Comment: Comento un pequeño error, dice uba en vez de una.

Answer (score 1):

Prueba haciendo la funcion `ocultar()` y asignando el `onclick` como atributo del boton.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

     function ocultar(){
        var imagen = document.getElementById('foto');
        imagen.style.display ='none';
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="boton" onclick="ocultar();">Click</button>
    <img src="header.jpg" id="foto">
</body>
```

---

Si no, prueba con JQuery:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
      $('#boton').on('click', function() {

        var imagen = document.getElementById('foto');
        imagen.style.display = 'none';

      });

    });
```

```css
#boton {
  width: 50px;
  height: 30px;
  display: block;
  margin: 30px;
}

img {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <button id="boton">Click</button>
  <img src="http://icdn.pro/images/es/j/p/jpg-imagen-icono-8802-128.png" id="foto">
</body>
```

Comment: La idea es evitar hacer uso del inline, y hacer uso de los eventos directamente desde el documento .js externo.

Comment: @jogofus  inline, a que te refieres?  si quieres que todo el js esté en un archivo externo usa jquery como te indico o con un evento `window.onload`

Answer (score 1):

Segun el flujo **html**: primero se ejecuta el `<script>` y luego el `<body>`, te recomiendo colocar el `<script>` despues del `<body>`:

```html
<body>
    <button id="boton">Click</button>
    <img src="header.jpg" id="foto">
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
 var boton = document.getElementById('boton');
 boton.onclick = function(){
  var imagen = document.getElementById('foto');
  imagen.style.display ='none';
 }
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

En problema con el que te estás encontrando es que el botón aún no está cargado en el DOM cuando el javascript se ejecuta.
En el jsFiddle que proporcionaron en el comentario esto no ocurre, ya que jsFiddle ya se encarga de cargar el javascript en el evento correspondiente.

Hay muchas formas de conseguir que el código se ejecute cuando el DOM haya terminado de cargar.

Poner el código al final del body.

### Invertimos el orden y ponemos la etiqueta script al final de la etiqueta body:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style type="text/css">
        #boton{
            width: 50px;
            height: 30px;
            display: block;
            margin:30px;
        }

        img{
            width: 300px;
            height: 200px;
            margin:30px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="boton">Click</button>
    <img src="header.jpg" id="foto">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var boton = document.getElementById('boton');
        boton.onclick = function(){
            var imagen = document.getElementById('foto');
            imagen.style.display ='none';
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

### Usamos el evento 'DOMContentLoaded' del objeto `document`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
            var boton = document.getElementById('boton');
            boton.onclick = function(){
                var imagen = document.getElementById('foto');
                imagen.style.display ='none';
            }
}, false);
        </script>
```

### Usamos el evento 'load' del objeto `window`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
            var boton = document.getElementById('boton');
            boton.onclick = function(){
                var imagen = document.getElementById('foto');
                imagen.style.display ='none';
            }
}, false);
        </script>
```

U

### samos el evento 'onreadystatechange' del objeto `document`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.attachEvent('load', function() {
            var boton = document.getElementById('boton');
            boton.onclick = function(){
                var imagen = document.getElementById('foto');
                imagen.style.display ='none';
            }
});
        </script>
```

### Usamos el evento 'onload' del objeto `window`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.attachEvent('onload', function() {
            var boton = document.getElementById('boton');
            boton.onclick = function(){
                var imagen = document.getElementById('foto');
                imagen.style.display ='none';
            }
});
        </script>
```

¿Por que hay tantos eventos y tantas posibilidades? ¿No resulta eso algo más confuso?

El motivo principal se debe a una cuestión de compatibilidad. Por ejemplo `DOMContentLoaded` es el evento que está más extendido, pero sin embargo no funciona en IE8 y anteriores.

Comment: @downvoters Es posible que me equivoque y no sea ese el problema pero a que son debidos los downvotes? Agradecería un comentario para comprender el problema con la respuesta.

Comment: Los scripts se ejecutan cuando el Dom ah terminado de cargar ([documentación](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/internals/howbrowserswork/)), si bien lo que publicas es una buena práctica, esto no es una solución.

Comment: Al tratarse de una funcion que se llama al realizarse en un evento como es el del click en un determinado elemento, no deberia ejecutarse sin tener que cargarse cuando termine la pagina? Hace un par de años lo ejecutaba asi, sin cargarlo con window.onload y corria perfectamente.

Comment: Y así sería si no estuviera esta línea en el Javascript `var boton = document.getElementById('boton');` Si esa línea de javascript se ejecuta antes de que el elemento con `ID='boton'` se renderize, no se va a poder asociar el evento. Al menos ese es el problema que me pareció entender que te estaba ocurriendo.

Comment: @GabrielJeremyRodriguezRiver Añadido a mi comentario anterior, he realizado un pequeño test para ilustrar lo que quiero decir: https://jsfiddle.net/7xf8nu0k/1/ En ese jsfiddle, vemos que la línea de javascript se ha ejecutado antes de que el botón se haya renderizado. Y muestra que el botón es `NULL`. Si por el contrario, cambiamos el orden del script, vemos que el botón es recuperado correctamente y muestra el nodo html: https://jsfiddle.net/7xf8nu0k/2/

Comment: @frikinside Esto sucede, porque no esta en el header, que es cosa distinta si lees la documentación, estas ejecutando código sobre dom no cargado (javascript dentro del body), ahora si colocas scripts dentro del TAG Header si se ejecutan cuando se ha terminado de cargar el DOM. de igual manera es una buena practica colocar los scripts dentro del body pero justo al final.

Comment: @GabrielJeremyRodriguezRiver Eso que comentas si te soy sincero, ni mi formación previa ni en mi experiencia tenía conocimientos de que ese flujo de ejecución fucionase como comentas. Por si acaso estaba viviendo engañado he hecho la prueba con un html local poniendo el código en el `head` y el resultado ha sido el mismo. He estado mirando la documentación también y no encontré la referencia a la ejecución que comentas. Podrías por favor indicarme donde se encuentra esa referencia que comentas? Por mucho que lleves años trabajando en esto nunca se deja de aprender ;)

Comment: @GabrielJeremyRodriguezRiver, ¿Podrías mostrarnos la documentación donde se dice exactamente que los script declarados en la TAG [Head](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_head.asp) (que no [Header](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_header.asp)) se ejecutan cuando se ha cargado el DOM? De ser así, la anotación `$( document ).ready() ` de jQuery, por ejemplo, sería casi innecesaria.